# python: problem using call.subprocess to use a file after writing it

Tags: python, subprocess

In python I am trying to write a script that will edit text files and then run executables that use those text files.  It basically entails 1)opening and reading/writing to a text file, and 2)using the file I just wrote in a bash command.  Here is a simple example:

```
import subprocess

# write file
a = ['1\n','2\n','3\n','4\n','5th and final line']
f = open('junk01.txt', 'wb')
f.writelines(a)
f.close

# show file
subprocess.call('cat junk01.txt', shell=True)
```

For some reason on that `subprocess.call` command it is not showing the contents of the junk01.txt file.  However after I run this code and type `cat junk01.txt` in bash the file has been written properly.  Similarly, I'm finding that after I open, write to, and close a text file and then try to use it in an executable, the file hasn't been written to yet.  Any explanation on why this is and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 9):

Close the file by actually calling the close() method.  This will implicitly flush the buffers to disk.

```
f.close()
```

rather than

```
f.close     #this probably doesn't do anything, but if there was no close method it would raise an error.
```

Comment: Is that all my problem was?  Wow, I feel like an idiot.  I gave it a try and sure enough, it works.

This is what I get for trying to do something complex in a language I just started learning last week...  Thanks!

Comment: Forgetting to flush the output has caught me years after I should have "known better" - I have a feeling it's a common error.

Comment: f.close does do something.  I locates the close method function.  Doesn't evaluate it, but it at least finds it.

Answer (score 0):

Although the first answer is most definitely correct and proper, you could also just set f to None instead of was was done as follows:

```
import subprocess

# write file
a = ['1\n','2\n','3\n','4\n','5th and final line\n']
f = open('junk01.txt', 'wb')
f.writelines(a)
f = None
# show file
subprocess.call('cat junk01.txt', shell=True)
```

~

Setting f to None takes the variable out of service and causes the file to be closed implicitly instead of being explicitly closed (as in the first preferred example)
I don't advocate this style of writing code as its a bit sloppy, I just mention it as an alternative solution.

```
[centos@localhost ~/test/stack]$  python 1.py
1
2
3
4
5th and final line
[centos@localhost ~/test/stack]$
```